# PostgreSQL: save data outside Docker-container

Tags: database, postgresql, docker, directory

I have a task of saving data outside container - in a host directory.
For this purporse I tried the following steps:

1. Change directory of data-saving;
2. Bind volume of default data-saving postgres-directory in container with the directory on my host, assigned on previous step.

My docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

    services:

      psql2:
       container_name: docker_db_test
       image: postgres:11
       volumes:
          - "/home/andrej/docker_psql:/var/lib/postgresql/data/base"
       command: bash -c "initdb -D /home/andrej/docker_psql"
       command: postgres
```

By "initdb -D /home/andrej/docker_psql" I change default-directory

Then I enter in container and successfully create database.

But database appeared in docker-directory (/var/lib/postgresql/data/base). Not in   /home/andrej/docker_psql

Additionally I changed the PGDATA in /etc/init.d/postgresql with:

```
PGDATA=/home/andrej/docker_psql
export PGDATA
```

Comment: Remove 2 `command` lines and replace volume entry with this: `/home/andrej/docker_psql:/var/lib/postgresql/data` and you will be fine.

Comment: Remove either command:bash  and  command: postgres  ?

Comment: Yes  remove both of them.

Comment: Done.   But... without success. Data continue to appear inside container...

Comment: It is normal to appear inside container. The point of using volumes is that container's `/var/lib/postgresql/data` directory is bound to `/home/andrej/docker_psql` of host. Have you checked `/home/andrej/docker_psql`? Do you see any data?

Comment: Yes, I checked - no data appeared in /home/andrej/docker_psql.   More than, my task is data-storing only in host directory (without duplicate in dontainer)

Comment: leopal, sorry, your advice was usefull in a part of appearence data both in host and docker-inside.  Data have not been stored in host, unlil I have not solved local problem with previous container, which binded volume in new container.  But other part of problen is not solved: data must be stored only in host-directory, not in container.

Comment: By using volume, data is only saved on the host's directory. You can see data from the container since container is not aware of volume's existence. Saying that, you can delete the container and start over, your data won't be lost.